# SwiftUI sign in with Apple [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, sign-in-with-apple

I have a sign in with apple button and I get multiple logs on the console when I build the view.

```
SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn, onRequest: { request in
    isLoggingIn = true
    
    request.requestedScopes = [.email]
}, onCompletion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let authResults):
        guard let credentials = authResults.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, let identityToken = credentials.identityToken, let identityTokenString = String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        
        print("success")
        
        repo.loginwithApple(appleTokenIDString: identityTokenString) { user, error in
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        isLoggingIn = false
    }
})
.signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme != .light ? .black : .white)
.disabled(isLoggingIn)
```

The logs:

[image]

```
2023-03-20 11:33:12.844732+0200 iosApp[56085:5272326] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f697c0 h=-&- v=-&- ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':_TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f698b0 h=-&- v=-&- H:[ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f69a40 h=--& v=--& _TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0.width
== 414   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281f62f80 ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.width <= 375   (active)>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x281f62f80 ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.width <= 375   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2023-03-20 11:33:12.845148+0200 iosApp[56085:5272326] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f69900 h=-&- v=-&- ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':_TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f69950 h=-&- v=-&- V:[ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281f69ae0 h=--& v=--& _TtGC7SwiftUI16PlatformViewHostGVS_P10$1b5309f8832PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptorV31_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUIP10$22c416d5817ViewRepresentable__:0x106c2e3f0.height
== 445   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281f63020 ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.height <= 64   (active)>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x281f63020 ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton:0x106c2d9a0.height <= 64   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I added as code as well.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: These sorts of constraint error messages indicate that `translateAutoresizingMarkIntoConstraints` has not been set to `false` and the constraints that iOS creates to mimic the old autoresizing mask behaviour is clashing with other constraints. However, since you are using SwiftUI and not UIKit I don't think there is anything you can do to fix this. It might just be a bug in Apple's implementation of the sign in button.

Comment: Are you (directly or indirectly) trying to set a frame for the sign in button that is either wider than 375 points or taller than 64 points? The constraints that iOS is breaking refers to those sizes.

Comment: I am not setting the frame, how I can set the size?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by directly setting the frame. As per the warning message, the max width of the button is `375` and the max height is `64`. By directly setting the properties to be within those constraints you no longer get the warning.

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn, onRequest: { request in
    isLoggingIn = true
    
    request.requestedScopes = [.email]
}, onCompletion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let authResults):
        guard let credentials = authResults.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, let identityToken = credentials.identityToken, let identityTokenString = String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        
        print("success")
        
        repo.loginwithApple(appleTokenIDString: identityTokenString) { user, error in
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        isLoggingIn = false
    }
})
.signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme != .light ? .black : .white)
.disabled(isLoggingIn)
.frame(maxWidth: 375)
.frame(height: 44)
```